# Getting a country code - Service or Utility method?

Tags: service, domain-driven-design, utility

Getting a country code or internal id might require accessing a database or simply loading a properties file.

How would such a method be placed in an application though? As a utility method it would look out of place so would it fit in an Application Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDD this type of method would be placed in a [repository](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/20/ddd-the-repository-pattern.aspx), which is basically an abstraction of a data access layer. For something like country codes you could consider caching the data since it is static.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, countries do not have internal ids.  (Your domain may be different.)  So, if it doesn't exist in your domain, and you're doing domain-driven design, you're going to want to avoid an artificial concept like country id.

Let's assume you've got an `Address` table in the database.  Instead of storing `CountryId`, store the `CountryAbbreviation` instead.  This is a natural key.

Now, how do you make sure that your Address only had valid country_id?  If you are in control of all the clients (e.g.) then you do something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="US">United States</option
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option
</select>
```

Above, you can see that the `value` attribute is the country abbreviation.

Unless reports are being based off country abbreviations, you don't really need to make sure they're super-consistent (unless it's super important to your domain).